# Format ForegroundRole for individual cell

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

I got the majority of this code from [QTableView refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669863/how-to-make-qtableview-refresh-background-color-after-it-loads-data-again).

I have data pulled from SQL database and present it to a a QAbstractTableModel via a Pandas DataFrame and display it with a QTableView. Everything is working (Thanks to significant help from the above mentioned article). The issue now is that I would like to just color the text in the 2nd column which is the same column I utilize in the color decision in the data function.

I have debugged the code to see that the value in the "it" variable is only the the value that I want to color so it seems to me that when the "return qtg.QBrush(qtc.QT."COLOR") is applied that it would only color that data but instead it colors the whole row.

Any help in understanding how this bit of code is working would be greatly appreciated!

```
import sys
import threading

import pandas as pd

from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw

import data
import pyodbc


class PandasManager(qtc.QObject):
    dataFrameChanged = qtc.pyqtSignal(pd.DataFrame)

    def start(self):
        self.t = threading.Timer(0, self.load)
        self.t.start()

    def load(self):
        df = data.get_data()

        self.dataFrameChanged.emit(df)
        self.t = threading.Timer(5.0, self.load)
        self.t.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.t.cancel()


class PandasModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        qtc.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._df = df

    @qtc.pyqtSlot(pd.DataFrame)
    def setDataFrame(self, df):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._df = df
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._df.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._df.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=qtc.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():  #Checking the validity of the index
            if role == qtc.Qt.ForegroundRole: # The role for text color
                if self.columnCount() >= 3 : # checking the number of columns is greater than 3 (Should be 5)
                    it = self._df.iloc[index.row(), 1] # Finds the specific data (second column) to test and assigns it to the variable "it"
                    if it == "WE": # If the value matches
                        return qtg.QBrush(qtc.Qt.yellow) #Color -- I may not quite understand what this is actually doing
                    if it == "UMaint": # Another value to match
                        return qtg.QBrush(qtc.Qt.green) # Another color
            if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole: # If not ForegroundRole but is DisplayRole
                return str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]) #Set value

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == qtc.Qt.Horizontal and role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._df.columns[col]
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = qtw.QTableView()
    model = PandasModel()
    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()

    manager = PandasManager()
    manager.dataFrameChanged.connect(model.setDataFrame)
    manager.start()

    ret = app.exec_()

    manager.stop()

    sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: I posted my whole code, check the edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the code working like I wanted and I am pasting it below. I am sure there is a much cleaner and more "pythonic" way of accomplishing it but it works.

As for what was the difference that made it work, I am not exactly sure. I did implement a variable for the column index to help me understand what was going on and I removed the column count if statement but other than that I am not sure.

Here is my working code below that may hopefully assist others in the future.

```
def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        current_column = index.column()
        current_row = index.row()

        we_color = QtGui.QColor('#FF9900')
        wp_color = QtGui.QColor('#CCCC33')
        umaint_color = QtGui.QColor('#FF0000')
        smaint_color = QtGui.QColor('#FA8072')
        equipinstall_color = QtGui.QColor('#0066FF')
        upartwt_color = QtGui.QColor('#990099')
        le_color = QtGui.QColor('#CC6600')
        prodrun_color = QtGui.QColor('#00FF00')
        matlassist_color = QtGui.QColor('#CC9999')
        oqual_color = QtGui.QColor('#C993FF')
        equipeng_color = QtGui.QColor('#B22222')

        white_color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
        black_color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)

        if index.isValid():  # Checking the validity of the index
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:  # The role for text color
                if current_column == 1:  # checking the number of columns is greater than 3 (Should be 5)
                    it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), current_column]  # Finds the specific data (second column) to test and assigns it to the variable "it"
                    if it == "WE":  # If the value matches
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Color -- I may not quite understand what this is actually doing
                    if it == "WP":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "SMaint":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "UMaint":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(white_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "EquipInstall":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "UPartWt":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(white_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "LE":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "ProdRun":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "MatlAssist":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "OQual":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "EquipEng":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(black_color)  # Another color+

            if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole:  # The role for text color
                if current_column == 1:
                    it = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), current_column]  # Finds the specific data (second column) to test and assigns it to the variable "it"
                    if it == "WE":  # If the value matches
                        return QtGui.QBrush(we_color)  # Color -- I may not quite understand what this is actually doing
                    if it == "WP":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(wp_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "SMaint":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(smaint_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "UMaint":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(umaint_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "EquipInstall":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(equipinstall_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "UPartWt":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(upartwt_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "LE":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(le_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "ProdRun":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(prodrun_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "MatlAssist":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(matlassist_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "OQual":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(oqual_color)  # Another color+
                    if it == "EquipEng":  # Another value to match
                        return QtGui.QBrush(equipeng_color)  # Another color+

            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:  # If not ForegroundRole but is DisplayRole
                return str(self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])  # Set value
```